# How to read $x^n-1$ and $x^{n-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, pronunciation

Now, it may sound absurd, but I would like to know (if exists), how to read $(x^{n-1})$ and $(x^n-1)$ distinctly and practice this it in everyday Mathematics.

As of now, I read $(x^{n-1})$ as, "x whole raised to power n-1" and $(x^n-1)$ as " x raised to n whole minus 1".

Similar confusing scenarios are also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe "x to the nth power minus 1" and "x to the n minus one-th power"?

Comment: I typically read this using pauses. The first I read as "x to the *n minus one*" whereas the second I would read as "*x to the n* **minus one**".

Comment: Sometimes I say "$x$ to the quantity $n-1$" for $x^{n-1}$.

Comment: I once sat on a committee in which the candidates had to take a written Math exam and then read aloud everything they wrote in  public, including formulas and computations.  I guess I don't need to say that nobody understood anything.

Answer (score 3):

To read aloud I would say, "x to the power, pause, n minus 1", and "x to the power n, pause, minus 1". The position of the pause is used to communicate the implied brackets. If this is not clear enough, then "x to the power open bracket n minus 1 close bracket".

Answer (score 1):

For $x^{n-1}$, $``x$ whole raised to $n-1"$ looks great.

For $x^n - 1$, I'd suggest $``1$ less than $x^n"$

Comment: The second definition suggests $1-x^n=x^n-1$, which is clearly false. You should write $-1+x^n$.

Comment: No, It's not  @manooooh.

Comment: Isn't "less" the same as "minus" in these contexts, @emil?

Comment: @manooooh No, it's not!

Comment: maybe “less” but not “less than”

Answer (score 1):

For $x^{n-1}$: $x$ raised to the difference of $n$ and $1$. And for $x^n-1$: The difference of $x$, raised to $n$, and $1$.